# How can I find what password store Chromium's password manager is using?

Tags: password-store, chrome

[Arch's docs on Chromium Browser say that for the purposes of storing passwords it uses either](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chromium/Tips_and_tricks#Force_a_password_store)

- `gnome`, uses Gnome Keyring
- `kwallet5`, uses KDE Wallet
- `basic`, saves the passwords and the cookies' encryption key as plain text in the file Login Data
- `detect`, the default auto-detect behavior

Is there anyway to find out which one it is using. I know Chrome is configured in many places, like `/etc/default/google-chrome` and in many other places for the user, system, and session. How do I know which Password Store Crhomium is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found running it with the verbose flag gave me what I was looking for, `chromium-browser --verbose`

```
[VERBOSE1:key_storage_util_linux.cc(53)] Password storage detected desktop environment: XFCE
[VERBOSE1:password_store_factory.cc(235)] Trying libsecret for password storage.
[VERBOSE1:key_storage_linux.cc(61)] OSCrypt using Libsecret as backend.
[VERBOSE1:password_store_factory.cc(238)] Using libsecret keyring for password storage.
```

I was able to get my browser to work under a different window manager by force providing `--password_store=gnome`

Comment: It is `--password-store=gnome`. I tried it, but only the first one of those lines did not appear. I am using Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Besides, storing passwords still changes '~/.config/chromium/Default/Login Data'.

Comment: Even if `gnome-keyring-daemon` is running.

Comment: [libsecret](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Libsecret) may communicate with gnome-keyring-daemon.

Comment: Currently the correct flags are `--enable-logging=stderr --v=1`. [1](https://github.com/flathub/com.google.Chrome/issues/9#issuecomment-695363079) [2](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: @jarno Open "Login Data" as SQLite and look at what it stores. I believe GNOME Keyring/KDE Wallet stores a master key, and then Chromium uses that to encrypt passwords in "Login Data".